# Recursive Power

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, recursion

I'm trying to calculate power of a number using recursion. What here I'm trying to do is setting the base argument as base* pow and reducing the pow argument every time.

I get an error: `source.cpp:21:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

```
int power(int base, int pow){
    if(pow!= 0){
        return power(base* pow, pow- 1);
    }
    if(pow== 0){
        return base;
    }
}
int main() {

    int x= power(2, 3);
    cout<<x;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because both return statements are within `if` statements the compile believes that your function may return nothing. Even if it logically never will, the compile cannot see that. Assuming this works properly, just stick `return -1;` at the end.

Comment: You don't need the second if, you could return unconditionally instead because you know  pow is always 0 when it hits that point.

Comment: This seems to be based on the arithmetic non-identity b^p = (b*p)^(p-1)

Comment: @DerekC. — if you do that, some other compiler will complain about unreachable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the function always returns a value (even though in this case, it obviously does). Also, your recursive formula is incorrect. You could do something like this instead:

```
int power(int base, int pow){
    if(pow != 0){
        return base * power(base, pow - 1);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WFgAhL).

Comment: Thank you, I eventually was lead to do the same solution because the code above tries to multiply base with the power.